# Angular: ng serve gives "webpack: Failed to compile"

Tags: angular

I started the [Angular QuickStart tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart), but got stuck right in the first part.

#### What I did

I followed the guide, and up to `ng serve --open` all went nicely, while this command gave an error `webpack: Failed to compile` after some other error messages, and the browser opened just displayed: `Cannot GET /`

#### Full error log:

```
C:\Users\ppete\Documents\DEV\!Angular\test1>ng serve --open
** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200 **
 10% building modules 6/9 modules 3 active ...1\node_modules\webpack\hot\emitter.jswebpack: wait until bundle finished: /                                    Hash: 5e52a4b2b9800e47679f
Time: 5094ms
chunk    {0} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 40 bytes {3} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {1} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 28 bytes {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {2} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 28 bytes {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {3} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map (vendor) 302 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {4} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 0 bytes [entry] [rendered]

ERROR in multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\Users\ppete\Documents\DEV\' in 'C:\Users\ppete\Documents\DEV\!Angular\test1\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\webpack-configs'
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts

ERROR in multi ./src/polyfills.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\Users\ppete\Documents\DEV\' in 'C:\Users\ppete\Documents\DEV\!Angular\test1\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\webpack-configs'
 @ multi ./src/polyfills.ts

ERROR in multi ./src/styles.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\Users\ppete\Documents\DEV\' in 'C:\Users\ppete\Documents\DEV\!Angular\test1\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\webpack-configs'
 @ multi ./src/styles.css

ERROR in   Error: Child compilation failed:
  Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\Users\ppete\Documents\DEV\' in 'C:\Users\ppete\Documents\DEV\!Angular  \test1\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\webpack-configs':
  Error: Can't resolve 'C:\Users\ppete\Documents\DEV\' in 'C:\Users\ppete\Documents\DEV\!Angular\test1\node_modules\@ang  ular\cli\models\webpack-configs'

  - compiler.js:76
    [test1]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/compiler.js:76:16

  - Compiler.js:291 Compiler.<anonymous>
    [test1]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:291:10

  - Compiler.js:494
    [test1]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:494:13

  - Tapable.js:138 next
    [test1]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:138:11

  - CachePlugin.js:62 Compiler.<anonymous>
    [test1]/[webpack]/lib/CachePlugin.js:62:5

  - Tapable.js:142 Compiler.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
    [test1]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:142:13

  - Compiler.js:491
    [test1]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:491:10

  - Tapable.js:131 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
    [test1]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:131:46

  - Compilation.js:645 self.applyPluginsAsync.err
    [test1]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:645:19

  - Tapable.js:131 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
    [test1]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:131:46

  - Compilation.js:636 self.applyPluginsAsync.err
    [test1]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:636:11

  - Tapable.js:131 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
    [test1]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:131:46

  - Compilation.js:631 self.applyPluginsAsync.err
    [test1]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:631:10

  - Tapable.js:131 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
    [test1]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:131:46

  - Compilation.js:627 sealPart2
    [test1]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:627:9

  - Tapable.js:131 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
    [test1]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:131:46


webpack: Failed to compile.
```

#### Versions

```
@angular/cli: 1.1.2
node: 8.1.2
os: win32 x64
@angular/animations: 4.2.3
@angular/common: 4.2.3
@angular/compiler: 4.2.3
@angular/core: 4.2.3
@angular/forms: 4.2.3
@angular/http: 4.2.3
@angular/platform-browser: 4.2.3
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.2.3
@angular/router: 4.2.3
@angular/cli: 1.1.2
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.2.3
@angular/language-service: 4.2.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6723), caused by the folder whose name starts with an exclamation mark in the path to the project:

```
C:\Users\ppete\Documents\DEV\!Angular\test1
```

Note the **`!Angular`** folder in the middle.

Running the same from the folder `C:\Users\ppete\Documents\DEV\Angular\test1` (Note: no **"!"** in there) results in correct operation:

```
C:\Users\ppete\Documents\DEV\Angular\test1>ng serve --open
** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200 **
 10% building modules 6/9 modules 3 active ...ode_modules\style-loader\addStyles.jswebpack: wait until bundle finished: /             Hash: 207adb8e1440eb67702b
Time: 13703ms
chunk    {0} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 160 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {1} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 5.34 kB {3} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {2} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 10.5 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {3} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map (vendor) 2.18 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {4} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 0 bytes [entry] [rendered]
webpack: Compiled successfully.
```

**TL;DR**
Some explanation about the issue:

- Angular CLI uses [webpack](https://webpack.github.io)
- Webpack uses the [AMD, Asynchronous Module Definition API](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api) for handling of the [Loaders](https://webpack.github.io/docs/loaders.html)
- The [AMD specification](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/blob/master/AMD.md) contains this part when detailing the module IDs:

  > If Loader Plugins are supported in the AMD implementation, then "!" is used to separate the loader plugin's module id from the plugin's resource id. Since plugin resource ids can be extremely free-form, most characters should be allowed for plugin resource ids.

So all in all the bug is caused by a **[wrong design decision](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/issues/34)**.

Comment: Are you sure to run you ng serve --open at the root of your project, I mean you have to be at the same level (/) as your package.json/src folder/node_modules folder

Comment: @EmileCantero Yes, that is the folder (I didn't mention, but I changed `my-app` to be `test1` - I like to see how things work from the inside, and make small changes to see how that affects the outcome... So in my case, instead of `my-app`, my folder is `test1`. (Also, was it not in the right folder, I assume it should not start properly)

Comment: @EmileCantero Well, I expected it to work in a folder name agnostic way, but otherwise yes, I'm able to compile and run Angular apps now.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue but rather than exclamation mark, my folder name had a hashtag. Changing the folder name solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

I also same faced an issue. i followed below steps.

1. Comment out error lines
2. run `ng serve` -- this time webpack run successfully
3. Uncommented previous line
4. Webpack is running successfully

Comment: Where are them?